# Error in related DropDownList's when page refreshes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two related ddl's. When page loads, I can POST them to controller and everything is ok. But also I have some fields in page, and if they are empy I call `ModalError` in my controller, then page should be reloaded with text of errors. But it throughs an error, that says `IEnumerable<SelectList>` with name `City` is empty. What is the problem?

View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_name)        
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_name)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_email)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_email)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_phone)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_phone)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Buyer.buyers_phone)
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Выберите адрес доставки:</h2>
    <h3>Выберите город</h3>
    @Html.DropDownList("City", ViewBag.cities as SelectList, new { id = "city" })
    <h3>Выберите адрес</h3>
    @Html.DropDownList("Address", ViewBag.addresses as SelectList, new { id = "address" })
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />

}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetItems(decimal id)
    {
        return PartialView(_db.bs_delivery_type.Where(x => x.delivery_city_id == id).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Checkout()
    {
        int selectedIndex = 1;
        SelectList cities = new SelectList(_db.bs_cities, "cities_id", "cities_name", selectedIndex);
        ViewBag.cities = cities;
        SelectList addresses = new SelectList(_db.bs_delivery_type.Where(x => x.delivery_city_id == selectedIndex), "delivery_id", "delivery_address");
        ViewBag.addresses = addresses;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Checkout(Cart cart, DeliveryModel deliveryModel, decimal city, decimal address)
    {
        if (cart.Lines.Count() == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your cart is empty");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //adds to db;
            return View("Completed");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(deliveryModel);
        }
    }
```

DeliveryModel:

```
public class DeliveryModel
{
    public bs_buyers Buyer { get; set; }
    public List<bs_cities> CitiesModel { get; set; }
    public SelectList FilteredDelivery { get; set; }
}
```

Also PartialView GetItems:

```
<select id="address" name="Address">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option value="@item.delivery_id">@item.delivery_address</option>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you invoke the Checkout Action in your Controller via HttpPost you then return the Checkout View in case the ModelState is invalid. However you do net set your ViewBag Variables as you do in your HttpGet Action.

You have to set ViewBag Variables in each and every Action. In this case I would recommend a separate method that gets invoked in both Actions.

```
private void SetViewBagForCheckout(){
    int selectedIndex = 1;
    SelectList cities = new SelectList(_db.bs_cities, "cities_id", "cities_name", selectedIndex);
    ViewBag.cities = cities;
    SelectList addresses = new SelectList(_db.bs_delivery_type.Where(x => x.delivery_city_id == selectedIndex), "delivery_id", "delivery_address");
    ViewBag.addresses = addresses;
}
```